Firebase Realtime Database Requests Timing Out on Vercel Deployment But Working Locally
I'm encountering an issue when trying to send requests to my Firebase Realtime Database from a Vercel-deployed application. The same requests work perfectly fine in my local development environment, both in development and production modes. However, once deployed on Vercel, I consistently receive timeouts and Firebase warnings.
Example of the Code That's Failing:
Here's a minimal, reproducible example of the serverless function that fails when deployed on Vercel:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { adminDb } from '@/lib';
import { env } from '@/lib';

const headers = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": env.CORS_ORIGIN,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
};

export async function OPTIONS(request: NextRequest) {
  return new Response(null, {
    status: 204,
    headers,
  });
}

export async function GET(request: NextRequest, context: { params: { tab: string, nameOrId: string } }) {
  if (!adminDb) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: "Service Unavailable",
        result: "fail",
        message: "Firebase services are not available",
      },
      {
        status: 503,
        headers: headers,
      }
    );
  }

  const { tab, nameOrId } = context.params;
  const refPath = `info/${tab}/${nameOrId}`;
  const infoRef = adminDb.ref(refPath);
  const snapshot = await infoRef.get();

  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const info = snapshot.val();
    return NextResponse.json({ success: true, info }, { status: 200, headers });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ error: "Info not found" }, { status: 404, headers });
}

Observations:

Firebase Realtime Database is throwing warnings, but the message is {}.
Multiple 504 Gateway Timeout errors are being returned by Vercel, indicating that the serverless function is not completing within the 10-second limit.

Logs from Vercel:
Aug 30 12:25:46.97
GET
---
bsb-backend.vercel.app
/api/public/images/slideshow
[2024-08-30T10:25:46.973Z] @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {}

Aug 30 12:25:46.52
GET
---
bsb-backend.vercel.app
/api/public/images/footer
[2024-08-30T10:25:46.526Z] @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {}

Aug 30 12:25:47.07
GET
---
bsb-backend.vercel.app
/api/public/images/footer
Vercel Runtime Timeout Error: Task timed out after 10 seconds

Aug 30 12:25:37.08
GET
504
bsb-backend.vercel.app
/api/public/info/mottos
[GET] /api/public/info/mottos?nxtPtab=mottos status=504

Steps I've Taken:

Verified that my internet connection is stable.
Checked that the database is nearly empty, so size or latency shouldn't be an issue.
I'm using Firebase Admin SDK to interact with Firebase services.

Firebase Initialization Code:
Here’s a shorter version of the Firebase initialization code I’m using in my project:
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  });
}

const adminDb = admin.database();
const adminAuth = admin.auth();
const adminStorage = admin.storage();

export { admin, adminDb, adminAuth, adminStorage };

Context:

Deployment Platform: Vercel
Database: Firebase Realtime Database, with correct credentials and configurations.
SDK: Using Firebase Admin SDK in serverless functions.

Questions:

Why am I getting these FIREBASE WARNING: {} messages?
What could be causing the timeouts on Vercel when it works locally?
Are there specific optimizations or configurations I should consider for Firebase or Vercel to avoid these timeouts?

Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please edit the question to show a complete, minimal, reproducible example of the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Right now you're just showing init code, which isn't enough to understand what might be going wrong elsewhere.  I suggest also doing some debugging to figure out the line of the code that causes any unexpected error messages, and make sure you're showing that, along with your debugging details.

@DougStevenson I had it

I resolved the issue by saving the private key in the environment variables without the surrounding quotes.
Initially, I was storing the private key like this:
PRIVATE_KEY="---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----
ShfkkJHNJK
Jeidj
---END PRIVATE KEY----"

But the correct way to store it in Vercel is without the quotes:
PRIVATE_KEY=---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----
ShfkkJHNJK
Jeidj
---END PRIVATE KEY----

By removing the quotes, the Firebase Admin SDK was able to correctly read and initialize using the private key.

This answer should help others who might be facing a similar issue with environment variables and Firebase Admin SDK.
